npm error code TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE npm error TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
I got this error CODEBUILD: Amazon Linux 2023 x86_64 standard:5.0

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

This is a temporary solution until npm fix it, before doing npm install run this command

  - npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com/ --global


NPM install is failing in India, Mumbai, npm is checking on that https://status.npmjs.org/
Refer https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/7893

The issue is related to NPM's handling of unexpected caching responses from a third party provider. Please see https://status.npmjs.org/.
Package Install failures due to "304 Not Modified" responses in Mumbai, India region
It was fixed my npm after this issue noticed.
